# windows 10 IoT on Rspberry PI 2 not booting

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windowsiot

I have downloaded the IoT dashboard app and followed the instructions to flash a 128gb San Disk Micro SD.

The process seems to have gone well (no errors) Browsing the card shows folders, etc. However, when I then insert it into my Raspberry Pi 2 board and power it up I am getting output to the HDMI? (I see I should see the windows logo from looking at various pages etc.

am I missing something? or is there anything I can do to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the size of the micro SD card... The raspberry pi faq page on their website says they're only aware of up to 32gb working.

(Just dug out my pi2 to check the size of my sd card and it's 16gb which works fine.)

(Hope this link works... I'm posting via the app, but here goes!)

[Raspberry Pi FAQ](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#sdCards)

Comment: Thanks for that. I kind of thought this maybe the case but could find anything concrete online to back it up. I bought a new 16gb and flashed this and it booted up just fine. Also as Amazon had pre loaded 128gb cards I thought this would be fine too.

Comment: Wow, I just noticed that myself on Amazon... they'll expect some bad feedback soon enough then if people buy them (but £72 is a bit steep!). Glad you're up and running now though :)